How to backup a complete dataset in JSON format on Bigquery, using a scheduled query?
I would like to do a backup of some of my datasets in JSON format with a single row per table. I managed to get to the part where I convert each table into a single row, with all the data stored as a JSON.
The problem is the scheduled query I need to produce requires hundreds of UNION ALL to produce a query that will backup a single dataset.
For example:
select
    'mydataset' as dataset,
    'mytableA' as table,
    TO_JSON_STRING(array_agg(t)) as data,
    CURRENT_DATETIME() as backup_date,
from mydataset.mytableA as t
 union all select
    'mydataset' as dataset,
    'mytableB' as table,
    TO_JSON_STRING(array_agg(t)) as data,
    CURRENT_DATETIME() as backup_date,
from mydataset.mytableB as t

And so on...
I was pondering whether there's a way to perpahs do this recursively by tapping into the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, and using the list of table names to call the same subquery once per table in the dataset?

Dynamically iterating through a project & dataset can be done using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT. In this example I'm assuming a project google-analytics-prod has multiple tables named in a wildcard format like analytics_*. You can also hard code the schema name here. The query goes a step further and also dynamically iterates through a project.

DECLARE dataset_name STRING;
DECLARE dataset_counter INT64;
DECLARE table_name_ STRING;
DECLARE table_counter INT64;

-- Get list of datasets matching the pattern 'analytics_xxx'
CREATE TEMP TABLE datasets AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() rownumber, schema_name AS dataset_name
  FROM google-analytics-prod.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
  WHERE schema_name LIKE 'analytics_%'
);


SET dataset_counter = 1;
-- Iterate through datasets
WHILE dataset_counter <= (SELECT MAX(rownumber) FROM datasets)  DO

  -- Fetch the next dataset name
  SET dataset_name = (SELECT dataset_name FROM datasets WHERE rownumber = dataset_counter);
  
  -- Dynamically iterate through a datasets tables
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tables_for_bkp AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() rownumber, table_name
  FROM `google-analytics-prod.%s`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE 
  table_schema = '%s')
  """, dataset_name, dataset_name)
  ;
  SET table_counter = 1
  ;
  -- retrieve table name iteratively
  WHILE table_counter <= (SELECT MAX(rownumber) from tables_for_bkp) DO
    SET table_name_ = (SELECT table_name FROM tables_for_bkp WHERE rownumber = table_counter);

    --Perform backup for table name
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''
    INSERT INTO `google-analytics-prod.dataset.backup_table`
    select
    "%s" as dataset,
    "%s" as table,
    TO_JSON_STRING(array_agg(t)) as data,
    CURRENT_DATETIME() as backup_date,
from `google-analytics.%s.%s` as t
    ''', dataset_name, table_name_, dataset_name, table_name)
   ;
   SET table_counter = (table_counter +1);
   END WHILE;
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tables_for_bkup;
   SET dataset_counter = (dataset_counter + 1);
END WHILE;

