How do I use a dynamic variable in a FROM statement? I get a Table-valued function not found CONCAT
I'm doing an export of several BigQuery tables and I'm looking to create a loop to do so. See below.
DECLARE list_of_tables ARRAY\<STRING\>;
DECLARE table_name STRING;

SET list_of_tables = ARRAY(
  SELECT DISTINCT table_name 
  FROM `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` 
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_name, "^my_table") AND table_type = "BASE TABLE");

LOOP
SET table_name = list_of_tables\[OFFSET(counter)\];
    
    EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
      uri = CONCAT('gs://archive/', table_name, '_*.csv'),
      format = 'CSV',
      overwrite = TRUE
    ) AS (
    SELECT *
      FROM CONCAT('project.dataset.', table_name)
    );

END LOOP;

I get the error

Table-valued function not found: CONCAT

Is there a way for me to make use of the variable table_name to do a SELECT FROM?

Hi @kokokruunch For that you can use a list of table names you can use ARRAY_AGG and to pass the dynamic table name use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT.Refer this link1, link2, link 3.

Previous answer I gave with an example on how you can use what Puthineedi referenced. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78900286/how-to-backup-a-complete-dataset-in-json-format-on-bigquery-using-a-scheduled-q/78903063#78903063

Try this.
DECLARE list_of_tables ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE table_name STRING;
DECLARE count INT64;

SET count = 0;

SET list_of_tables = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(table_name)
  FROM `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_name, "^my_table") AND table_type = "BASE TABLE"
);

WHILE count < ARRAY_LENGTH(list_of_tables) DO
  SET table_name = list_of_tables[OFFSET(counter)];

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
    EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
      uri='gs://archive/%s_*.csv',
      format='CSV',
      overwrite=TRUE
    ) AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM `project.dataset.%s`
    )
  """, table_name, table_name);

  SET count = count + 1;
END WHILE;

